# Using my current 3G Sim with the iPad

Tags: ipad, sim

I'm thinking of buying an iPad at some point, the one with 3G.

I also have a 3G dongle that I'm not really using at the moment and wish to use on the iPad. I understand that it's a MicroSim, and I can chop my SIM down, but are there any 3G sim locks on the iPad itself?

The only thing I think I'll need to find out is the 3G settings (if it isn't locked). I'm in the UK and I have an orange contract.

So am I right in thinking that if the iPad is not locked to a certain 3G network, I can use this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPad with 3G is sold unlocked. In the UK, the iPad with 3G will work with Orange, Three, O2, and Vodafone.

To be pedantic, the iPad's 3G connection will not work with carriers such as **T-Mobile USA**, which in part uses the 1700 MHz frequency for 3G. The iPad with 3G supports the necessary frequencies to fully work in the UK with Orange, Three, O2, and Vodafone, and SIMs from these carriers can be swapped seamlessly.

Comment: Ah OK, so my Orange 3G Mobile BB sim will work on the iPad (if I chop it down to MicroSIM size)? I was worried that they'd try hook you into an iPad only deal, which I'm sure the network provider would like to do!

Comment: With the correct settings, it will work :)

Comment: Just so I know when I get my pad next week, does anyone know the Orange settings for 3g?

Comment: For Orange UK, the APN is `orangeinternet` and the username and password should be left blank.